# How to populate cells when matching data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my spreadsheet I need column E to populate with the corresponding value from column A when the values in column C are found in column B.

For instance, in the screenshot below I need E1 to E10 to be populated with the value in A1 because C1 to C10 match B1. And E11 and E12 need to be populated with the value in A2 because C11 and C12 match B2... and so fourth.

How can I do this without using VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one in `E1` and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,B:B,0)),"NOT Found")
```